# How do I create new objects within a loop?

Tags: java, arrays, object

First thing first, I am new to java so please have mercy.
I have created a Movie class and a MovieList class.
The MovieList class is basically an array that should contain movie objects

```
public class MovieList{
//fields
private Movie[] movieList = new Movie[100];
```

Now, in the MovieList class I have a method add movies that I should call in the main. Now my problem is, how can I create new Movie objects that I should add to the MovieList, within a for loop. Like creating an undefined number of movie objects that get their fields from the console. 
I have tried Movie movie1 = new Movie(); but within the for loop it gets overwritten and my MovieList ends up containing only the last movie1 I entered from the console. 
I have also tried creating a new array in the main that would contain empty movie objects and that I would set their fields within the for loop, but the array is also limited and I can't seem to be able to increment it.
Is there anyway I can get a Movie movie2 = new Movie() ... and so on but use a variable for the "movie2" that I can somehow change to be movie3 ?

```
public static void shortMovie(Movie[] arrayMovie,int x,int y){
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  String title;
  int id;
  System.out.println("Now please enter the movies, just name and ID");
        for(int i=x; i<y; i++){
           System.out.println("Please enter the detail of the movie in this order");
           System.out.println("Please enter the title of the movie");
           title = console.next();
           System.out.println("Please enter the id of the movie");
           id = console.nextInt();
           arrayMovie[i].setTitle(title);
           arrayMovie[i].setId(id);
           }
```

}
I am using this method in the main, and an extra array that contains empty movie objects, but the array eventually ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the movie first.

In "shortMovie" method, Try:

```
arrayMovie[i] = new Movie();
arrayMovie[i].setTitle(title);
arrayMovie[i].setId(id);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if i understand your question correctly you will be needing a Collection object preferably a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to dynamically increment the size.

then your a loop to add movies which will look something like this.

```
            int index=0;       
            List<Movie> movieList = new LinkedList<Movie>();
            System.out.println("Enter the movie info ID and Title");
            while (index++ < size) {
                Movie movie = new Movie();
                System.out.println("Movie Title:");
                movie.setTitle(console.next());
                System.out.println("Movie Id:");
                movie.setId(console.nextInt());
                movieList.add(movie);
            }
            System.out.println(movieList.size()); // Count of movie added
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an ArrayList (or other dynamic collection) instead of an array:

```
List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
```

Then you'll be able to do the following from the console in your loop:

```
for(int i=x; i<y; i++){
    System.out.println("Please enter the detail of the movie in this order");
    System.out.println("Please enter the title of the movie");
    title = console.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the id of the movie");
    id = console.nextInt();
    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.setTitle(title);
    movie.setId(id);
    movieList.add(movie);
}
```

Alternatively if you do want to use an array it looks like all you're missing is to initialise each array entry before setting values like so:

```
arrayMovie[i] = new Movie();
arrayMovie[i].setTitle(title);
arrayMovie[i].setId(id);
```

Comment: I did, the problem was that the array is limited, but the an array list should solve the problem.

Comment: glad I was able to help. I should add that you access items in a `List<>` differently than a regular array: `movieList.get(i)`